Python, Scapy and exporting to an .exe
At the moment I play a little bit with scapy, Qt and python. So far everything worked fine when starting the programm with VSC.
Now I tried to make an .exe with PyInstaller. It also worked, I got an .exe-file, can open it and get my Qt-Windows displayed. But when I use a scapy-function the program crashes without any message and the window get closed.
I activated logging and find out, that the program crashed everytime we reaches following line of code:
ans, unans = sr(query, timeout=5)

With this line should be send a DNS-paket stored in the query-variable. And this step only fails in the exe.
These are my scapy-imports:
from scapy.layers.inet import IP, UDP
from scapy.layers.dns import DNS, DNSRR, DNSQR, DNSRROPT
from scapy.sendrecv import sr
from scapy.all import get_if_addr, conf

and this is my command-line for building the .exe:
-m PyInstaller --onefile -w --exclude=PySide6 --hidden-import=scapy.layers.dns --hidden-import=scapy.layers.inet --hidden-import=scapy.sendrecv --hidden-import=scapy.all
 --hidden-import=PyQt6 .\main.py

Anyone any idea?
I'm very lost, its my first application where I try to build an exe..
Thanks a lot!
Dennis

what is the error message you get?

That's the problem. There is no error-message....

if you know that is the line of code that is throwing an error, wrap it in a try catch, and log the error to a file. You would have to recompile the exe, but without the traceback there is not much to go off here

Ah ok. Got it. I‘ll try this also and share the results. Thanks a lot

Hi, so I tried your tip and get the following exception:
DEBUG:root:[Errno 9] Bad file descriptor

First, please delete -w and build the exe again.
Second, open a cmd window, drag and drop the exe on it, and run the exe with Enter. Try the scapy function again and the error message should show up.

At last, solve the error and build the exe still without -w. If there is no error showing up, then build the exe again with -w.
If you have a problem solving the error, leave a comment or put the error in your question. I will update my answer, too.

Thank you. I‘ll try that tomorrow and share the results with you.

Ok - this is crazy. If I build the exe without -w everything works as it should be.. when I build it again with -w the program chrashes.
So I tried the tip above with try except and get this exception in the log-file:
DEBUG:root:[Errno 9] Bad file descriptor

So one of the imported packages (maybe scapy) requires the command window to exist to perform normally. For example, if you build an flask app into exe, it will need the command window. So -w can not be used.

Yes I think so too.
I googled a bit about scapy and they need a cmd for processing there function..
Do you now a way to open the cmd in background and not visible for the user or is this not possible?

Sorry, I don't know how to hide it. If you know it someday, please share it with us.

Ok, thank's a lot. Now I knew what the problem is.
If I find a solution I will post it here.
